# I'm having a lot of trouble converting this C++ code reversing a character array in place to MIPS instructions

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

not sure if this is the right place to ask for help with coding problems. But I am trying to convert this code in C++ to MIPS instructions. I currently have this code to swap a character array in place:

```
void swap(char *a, char *b){
    char temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i, j;
    const int size = 5;
    char string[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    j = size - 1;
    for(i = 0; i < j; i++){
        swap(&string[i], &string[j]);
        j--;
    }
    cout << string;

    return 0;
}
```

The MIPS instructions I have now are:

```
.text 

    #size, i, j in $s0, $s1; $s2
    #base address of string in $s3
    addi $s0, $zero, 5      # size = 5
    add $s1, $zero, $zero       # i = 0
    add $s2, $s0, -1        # j = size - 1
    la $s3, string


forLoop1:       
    slt $t0, $s1, $s2       #i < j
    beq $t0, $zero, end1        #if i > j, branch end
    jal swap
    subi $s2, $s2, 1        #j--

end1:

#---------------------------------------------------------------
swap:
    lb $v0, 0($a0)      #get LHS byte
    lb $v1, 0($a1)      #get RHS byte

    sb $v1, 0($a0)      #store LHS byte
    sb $v0, 0($a1)      #store RHS byte

    jr $ra

.data

string: 
    .asciiz #hello
```

I'm very lost when it comes to writing MIPS instructions. Can anyone maybe give me some help or advice? One specific question I have would be, how do I set the pointers as arguments and how would I implement it? Also, how would I produce the output?

Comment: You never read or write anything to memory. You must do that in the swap function. Pass the correct pointers and load values from memory and write them back once exchanged. You do not increment i in your loop and do not test for loop end.

Comment: To read or write memory look at instructions `lb` and `sb`. The pointers are computed as in C, by adding a displacement to the base array address in `s3`.